# Can I use a 50 Ω attenuator with a high-Z scope?

Tags: rf, oscilloscope, high-impedance

In my project involving the measurement of current using a Pearson current transformer, the instructions specify the use of high-Z (1 MΩ) oscilloscopes. Given the need to attenuate the signal, I have a couple questions:

1. Can 50 Ω attenuators be employed to attenuate the signal?
2. If a mismatch occurs, is there a method or formula to calculate the true value of the current after attenuation?

Comment: What Pearson current transformer?

Comment: Pearson specifies that their current transformers, at least the ones I've used, can also be used with 50 Ω scope inputs, it'll just halve the sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

> Can 50 ohm attenuators be employed to attenuate the signal?

Yes, if you use a 50 \$\Omega\$ feed-thru terminator (or a Tee connector with a 50 \$\Omega\$ terminator attached to one of the ports) at your Hi-Z oscilloscope input, like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgY6cb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you omit the \$50 \Omega\$ termination, your attenuator will not give its designed attenuation, and you may have reflections on your coax when the signal reaches the hi-Z input of your oscilloscope.

Note that you do not need, and shouldn't use, a feed through terminator when using standard oscilloscope probes with a hi-Z oscilloscope input. Why? Because the cable for a standard oscilloscope probe is not a standard coax, although it may look like it from the outside. It is actually a high resistance (i.e. lossy) coax, designed to prevent reflections.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a feed-through; it could be a tee with a non-feedthrough terminator on one of them.

Comment: @Hearth excellent point.